# How to run a function x times in different clusters in r?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I have this command:
`replicate(10^4, binom_ttest(100, 0.5)) %>% {sum(.<0.05)}/20000`

`binom_ttest` is a function I have created that returns 2x `p.value` 1 for the binom test and 1 for the t test

As this is a very long calculation I wanted to ask how I can distribute it to 2 clusters?
I know there is a possibility with `parLapply` but this doesn't work:
`parLapply(makeCluster(2), 1:10000, binom_ttest(100, 0.5))`

Comment: What's the error message? Did you `clusterExport` your function?

Comment: @AndreWildberg Yes I did that. `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  2 nodes produced errors; first error: 'base::quote(c(0.0118179321289063, 0.00403591538162696))' is not function, sign oder symbol` not sure if I translated it 100 percent right, my R isn't english

Comment: I don't understand how are you doing a binomial test (binary variable) and a t-test (continuous variable). Can you explain your function better?

Comment: @RuiBarradas this is the function: `function(n, p) {
  x <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p))
  xsum <- sum(x==1) 
  p_binom <- binom.test(xsum, n, 0.5)[["p.value"]]
  p_ttest <- t.test(x, mu=0.5)[["p.value"]]
  c(p_binom, p_ttest)
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**future.apply**](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future.apply) package provides [`future_replicate()`](https://future.apply.futureverse.org/reference/future_lapply.html), which is a parallel implementation of `replicate()`;

```
library(future.apply)
plan(multisession, workers = 2)

y <- future_replicate(10^4, binom_ttest(100, 0.5))
```

It makes sure proper parallel random number generation (RNG) is used, which is critical when doing permutation tests, bootstrapping, etc.

Comment: That's a great package, thank you for the insight, works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example test run of `parallel`. I'd recommend to try a dry run with a simple function and then expand it to your more complicated example.

As a side note, every piece of data set you are using has to be available to all clusters and hence has to be exported like `simpl()` in the example below.

```
library(parallel)

cl <- makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 2))

cl
# socket cluster with 2 nodes on host ‘localhost’

simpl <- function(x)diag(x)

clusterExport(cl, varlist=("simpl"))

parLapply( cl, 1:5, function(x) simpl(x) )
#[[1]]
#     [,1]
#[1,]    1
#
#[[2]]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    0
#[2,]    0    1
#
#... etc
#
#[[5]]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    1    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[4,]    0    0    0    1    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    1

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: WARNING: Whenever random numbers are involved, you need to make sure use parallel RNG in order to get statistical sound results. See `?parallel::clusterSetRNGStream` for how to do that.

Comment: @HenrikB Thanks, that's an important note. I better include a simpler example...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way.
You forgot to export the function to the workers and in order to make the code reproducible, it's better to set the pseudo-RNG.

```
library(parallel)

binom_ttest <- function(n, p) {   
  x <- sample(0:1, n, replace = TRUE, prob = c(1-p, p))   
  xsum <- sum(x==1)    
  p_binom <- binom.test(xsum, n, 0.5)[["p.value"]]   
  p_ttest <- t.test(x, mu=0.5)[["p.value"]]   
  c(p_binom, p_ttest) 
}

cl <- makeCluster(2)
clusterExport(cl, "binom_ttest")
clusterSetRNGStream(cl = cl, 2021)
res <- parSapply(cl, 1:10000, FUN = function(i) binom_ttest(100, 0.5))
stopCluster(cl)

rowMeans(res < 0.05)
#[1] 0.0347 0.0571
```

Comment: FYI, you need to use `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream()` in order to set up parallel RNG on the parallel workers.

Comment: @HenrikB You are of course right, thanks. Corrected now.